# Using GWT's "shared" folder for storing EJB beans

Tags: java, gwt, ejb, javabeans

It is possible to use GWT's "shared" folder for storing beans, that will be used by EJB, GWT servlet **and gwt client(javascript)** side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but it will really limit what you can put inside those beans (not everything is supported in GWT). It is better to create a DTO layer or use [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html).